In which points is $f: \mathbb{R}P^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ an inmersion.
In this problem $\mathbb{R}P^2$ denotes the real proyective space of dimension $2$ which is obtained by identifying one dimensional spaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We denote by $\pi$ the usual projection from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to this space.
Edit: For the function to be well defined we take $\mathbb{R}P^2$ as the space that identifies antipodal points in $S^n$.
We consider the smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}P^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, $f([x,y,z]) = (xy,xz,yz)$. I'm trying to see in which points is this function an inmersion, and so I started by considering the usual charts in, for example $\varphi_1 :  \pi(U_1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\varphi_1([x,y,z]) = (\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x})$, and $U_1$ is the open set in which $x \neq 0$. This function has inverse given by $\varphi_1^{-1}(a,b) = [1,a,b]$ and so I tried to consider the localization of $f$ with this chart, that is $f \circ \varphi^{-1} (a,b) = (a,b,ab)$. However if we compute the derivative of $f \circ \varphi_1^{-1}$ we get:
$$
d(f\circ\varphi^{-1}) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Which clearly is a matrix with rank $2$, so $d(f\circ\phi^{-1})$ is inyective and similarly with the other charts of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ we get that $f$ would be an inmersion at every point of the space. Is this right or what am I missing?

It is well defined, you can think of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ with the equivalent definition on $S^n$ that identifies antipodal points. With this definition you can see that you only need to check wether or not f is well defined on a point and its antipodal, and so it is well defined because antipodal points change only by sign.
Although I don't know if by doing this you can introduce non inmersion points on $f$

If we take the projective space as in the space that identifies antipodal points in $S^n$ it is well defined, in this case is it true that $f$ is an immersion on every point?

Your chart $\phi_1$ is the one you would use if working with the projective space as the quotient $\Bbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb{RP}^2$, not $S^2\to\Bbb{RP}^2$. Thus your whole calculation is wrong.

Let $x,y,z:S^2\to\Bbb{R}$ be the restrictions of the usual functions $\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}$. Then, we have $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, so taking $d$ of both sides and dividing by $2$ yields
\begin{align}
x\,dx+y\,dy+z\,dz=0.\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
Now, consider the smooth map $F:S^2\to\Bbb{R}^3$ given by $F(x,y,z)=(xy,xz,yz)$. Then, $F$ is invariant under the antipodal map, so it descends to a smooth map $f:\Bbb{RP}^2\to\Bbb{R}^3$, which is precisely the map you have in question (this is the famous Steiner Roman surface). Our goal is to figure out when $f$ is an immersion; but notice that since $F=f\circ \pi$ and since $\pi$ is a covering map, it suffices to find points where $F$ is an immersion. We start by computing the differential of $F$:
\begin{align}
dF=(y\,dx+x\,dy,z\,dx+x\,dz,z\,dy+y\,dz).
\end{align}

Now, let us focus attention to those points in $S^2$ with $z\neq 0$. Then, $(x,y)$ forms a local coordinate system (we get one in the region $z>0$, and another in the region $z<0$). Also, rearranging $(*)$ and plugging into our equation for $dF$ gives
\begin{align}
dF&=\left(y\,dx+x\,dy,\frac{z^2-x^2}{z}\,dx-\frac{xy}{z}\,dy,\frac{-xy}{z}\,dx+\frac{z^2-y^2}{z}\,dy\right)\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
y&x\\
\frac{z^2-x^2}{z}&\frac{-xy}{z}\\
\frac{-xy}{z}&\frac{z^2-y^2}{z}
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
dx\\dy
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
We now have to investigate the rank of this coefficient matrix. Since $z\neq 0$, we can multiply the bottom two rows by $z$ without affecting the rank, i.e
\begin{align}
\text{rank}(dF)&=\text{rank}
\begin{pmatrix}
y&x\\
z^2-x^2&-xy\\
-xy&z^2-y^2
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Let $\det_{ij}$ be the determinant of the $2\times 2$ matrix obtained by taking rows $(i,j)$. Then, a simple calculation (using also the fact that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$) shows
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\det_{12}&=x(2x^2-1)\\
\det_{13}&=y(2z^2-1)\\
\det_{23}&=z^2(2z^2-1)
\end{cases}.
\end{align}
The rank is not full if and only if all three of these determinants vanish, i.e if and only if $(x,y,z)\in \{(0,\pm\alpha,\pm\alpha),(\pm\alpha,0,\pm\alpha)\}$, where for convenience of typing I have denoted $\alpha:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. So, there are exactly $8$ points in $S^2\cap\{z\neq 0\}$ where $F$ fails to be an immersion.
Similarly, if you work in the region $x\neq 0$, you’ll again find that $F$ fails to be an immersion at exactly the following $8$ points: $\{(\pm\alpha,\pm\alpha,0),(\pm\alpha,0,\pm\alpha)\}$.
Finally, in the region $y\neq 0$, $F$ fails to be an immersion at exactly the following $8$ points: $\{(\pm\alpha,\pm\alpha,0),(0,\pm\alpha,\pm\alpha)\}$.

So, putting this all together (keeping in mind some of the repetitions) there are a total of $12$ points on $S^2$ where $F$ fails to be an immersion: $\{(\pm\alpha,\pm\alpha,0),(\pm\alpha,0,\pm\alpha),(0,\pm\alpha,\pm\alpha)\}$. These $12$ points project down to exactly $6$ points in $\Bbb{RP}^2$, where $f$ fails to be an immersion:
\begin{align}
\{[\alpha:\alpha:0],[\alpha:-\alpha:0],[\alpha:0:\alpha],[\alpha:0:-\alpha],[0:\alpha,\alpha],[0:\alpha:-\alpha]\}.
\end{align}

Why is the differential of $F$ a 2 by 3 matrix? You started by taking $F$ on the whole space so it should be a 3 by 3 matrix. I assume that this is because when you restrict to $S^2$ then you simply take something like $z = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ but then you would have a function from $S^2$ to the whole space so you would need to compose with charts of $S^2$ to actually take the derivative is it not?

@H4z3 the differential of $F$ is a triple of $1$-forms. How do you check if three $1$-forms (which are linear combinations of the basis $1$-forms $dx,dy$) are independent? Stick the coefficients of $dx$ into one column and stick the coefficients of $dy$ into the other column and compute the rank (verifying that this procedure really does give the rank of $dF$ is very basic linear algebra… nothing really to do with manifolds).

Well, you could go through the motions of writing out $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$, and then plugging that in to get a function $\tilde{F}(x,y)=F(x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$ on a certain open subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$, and then compute the $3\times 2$ Jacobian matrix of this map. BUT, you don’t need to do all this. In my answer, I’m using $x,y,z$ to actually mean functions $S^2\to\Bbb{R}$, so I can take their exterior derivatives, and I can compute the exterior derivative of $F$, and I can use my equation $(*)$ which is a legit equality of $1$-forms on $S^2$.

everything I did pertains to equations about 1-forms on $S^2$ (or open subsets thereof), and I intentionally did not use any charts anywhere (simply to showcase how convenient differential forms are). I then restricted myself to the region $z\neq 0$ in my first bullet point so that ${dx,dy}$ is linearly independent here.

Another way of phrasing the calculations is to again focus attention on the region $z\neq 0$. Then, we have expressed $dF_1,dF_2,dF_3$ as linear combinations of $dx,dy$ (which in this region form a basis). In order to have that no two of these be linearly independent (i.e for $F$ to fail to be an immersion), we need all of $dF_1\wedge dF_2,dF_1\wedge dF_3,dF_2\wedge dF_3$ to vanish… but this is essentially my determinant calculation.

Oh well I was trying to avoid using anything to do with differential forms, that's why I was asking to do the substitution $z = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$

@H4z3 ok then you can just go ahead with the function $\tilde{F}$ defined above and compute its $3\times 2$ Jacobian matrix; you’ll get exactly what I have in my answer. Note btw that you actually didn’t have to explicitly solve $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ since all we care about are derivatives, so with implicit differentiation you can figure out the derivatives of the implicitly defined function $Z(x,y)$ satisfying $x^2+y^2+Z(x,y)^2=1$.

Oh thanks that's really helpful
